# Fast perl http server?

Tags: perl

This server will accept `GET`/`POST` requests and query `MySQL` or `memcached` then return data back to client.

There is no HTML part, so `Dancer` or `Catalyst` seems be too heavy.

Only thing I care is speed. Do you have some recommendation?

Comment: You appear to be confused, since Dancer and Catalyst aren't HTTP servers.

Comment: Yes, totally. I will ask another question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of them, including [Starman](http://p3rl.org/Starman), [Starlet](http://perl.org/Starlet) and [Feersum](http://p3rl.org/Feersum). All are capable of hosting PSGI apps (plus Feersum also has an older API for writing apps that predates PSGI). Starman is probably the most commonly used, which makes it a good enough choice.

As for lightweight frameworks, I would suggest [Web::Simple](http://p3rl.org/Web%3a%3aSimple), which is a really small bit of routing and request-decoding, and otherwise leaves you to deal with the PSGI interface yourself.